# Spring websocket authentication with spring security: 401 error

Tags: spring-security, spring-websocket, http-status-code-401

I would like to authenticate WebSocket with `spring security`. From [spring official document](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/html/websocket.html) `23.2 WebSocket Authentication`, WebSocket will reuse the same authentication information that is found in the HTTP request when the WebSocket connection is made. So I setup spring security to authenticate `rest service`. If the user passes the rest authentication, it will have permission to WebSocket connection, otherwise it can't establish WebSocket connection. Following is the code:

**Rest service for login: WssAuthService.java**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Authentication service.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/dm")
public class WssAuthService {
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(){
        return "Login success to WssBroker...";
    }
}
```

**spring security configuration: WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
 
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    public final static String REALM="MY_TEST_REALM";
     
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN")
        .and().withUser("test").password("test").roles("USER");
    }
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().realmName(REALM).authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint())
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);//We don't need sessions to be created.
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint(){
        return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // altough this seems like useless code,
        // its required to prevend spring boot auto-configuration
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

**websocket server configuration: WssBrokerConfig.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WssBrokerConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer  {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
            .nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/notification").permitAll()
            .simpDestMatchers("/**").authenticated()
//            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/**", "/topic/friends/*").hasRole("USER")
//            .simpTypeMatchers(MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE).denyAll()
            .anyMessage().denyAll();

    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        /**Note: setAllowedOrigins is important here: since we have both http & websocket servers, cross-origin accesses should be enabled */
        registry.addEndpoint("/dm-ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter =
                new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
        return converter;
    }

}
```

**websocket client:WebSocketClient.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompCommand;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompFrameHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSession;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompSessionHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.Transport;
import org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport;

//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class WebsocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // 1.login to rest service
        authToRest();
        // 2.establish websocket connection
        openConnection();
    }
    
    private static HttpHeaders getHeaders(){
        String plainCredentials="admin:admin";
        String base64Credentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainCredentials.getBytes());
         
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
        return headers;
    }
    
    public static void authToRest(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(getHeaders());
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8082/dm/login", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    }
    
    public static void openConnection(){
        List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
        WebSocketClient transport = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
        
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();
        stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler); // for heartbeats
        StompSessionHandler myHandler = new MyStompHandler();
        String url = "ws://localhost:8082/dm-ws";
        stompClient.connect(url, myHandler);
        
        //block the thread
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static class MyStompHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {
        
        @Override
        public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
            session.subscribe("/topic/response", new StompFrameHandler() {
                @Override
                public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                    return Object.class;
                }
                @Override
                public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                    System.out.println(payload);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload,
                Throwable exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("transport error.");
        }
    }
}
```

But the result turned out to be I can get the rest response but can't establish connection with WebSocket server. This is the error info:

```
14:31:35.368 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8082/dm/login" resulted in 200 (null)
14:31:35.369 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading [java.lang.String] as "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@4b553d26]
Login success to WssBroker...
14:31:35.415 [main] INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService 
14:31:35.569 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport - Executing SockJS Info request, url=http://localhost:8082/dm-ws/info
14:31:35.569 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://localhost:8082/dm-ws/info"
14:31:35.574 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8082/dm-ws/info" resulted in 401 (null); invoking error handler
14:31:35.578 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient - Initial SockJS "Info" request to server failed, url=ws://localhost:8082/dm-ws
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport.executeInfoRequestInternal(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractXhrTransport.executeInfoRequest(AbstractXhrTransport.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.getServerInfo(SockJsClient.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.doHandshake(SockJsClient.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:219)
    at com.hspi.dm.console.message.WebsocketClient.openConnection(WebsocketClient.java:66)
    at com.hspi.dm.console.message.WebsocketClient.main(WebsocketClient.java:35)
14:31:35.583 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession - Failed to connect session id=d8fda5d4-ba5a-7d22-f517-74e939096bfa
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.RestTemplateXhrTransport.executeInfoRequestInternal(RestTemplateXhrTransport.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractXhrTransport.executeInfoRequest(AbstractXhrTransport.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.getServerInfo(SockJsClient.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.SockJsClient.doHandshake(SockJsClient.java:254)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient.connect(WebSocketStompClient.java:219)
    at com.hspi.dm.console.message.WebsocketClient.openConnection(WebsocketClient.java:66)
    at com.hspi.dm.console.message.WebsocketClient.main(WebsocketClient.java:35)
```

Could someone help me? Thanks.

### Update

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640872/secure-spring-webscoket-using-spring-security-and-access-principal-from-websocke), the problem seems to be I didn't secure the `websocket endpoint`. I tried that two solutions but it didn't work, maybe I got the wrong way to do this. Wishing the correct way to secure `websocket endponit`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I misunderstood `WebSockets reuse the same authentication information that is found in the HTTP request when the WebSocket connection was made.` from [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/html/websocket.html).

I should have authenticated the HTTP request that upgrades to WebSocket rather than rest service. Meanwhile, there is something need to change with WebSocket configuration.

1.**Disable CSRF within WebSocket**

Add `sameOriginDisabled()` to `WssBrokerConfig`.

```
@Configuration
public class WssBrokerConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    ...

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

2.**Connect with WebSocketHttpHeaders**

Construct `WebSocketHttpHeaders` and add user credential to headers before `connect()`. The username and password should be encrypted with base64.

```
String plainCredentials="admin:admin";
String base64Credentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainCredentials.getBytes());

final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

stompClient.connect(url, headers, myHandler);
```